# Make a new page (print) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print in separate page javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435688/print-in-separate-page-javascript)

I have a bit of a problem. I want to make a page to print in HTML, and every third table (that's what I wanna print) shall be on a new page. But I can't find any method to make a new page in JS. Right now I've made a div that makes a space on 60px, but when I e.g. remove the adressbar and stuff in the print-promt (Google Chrome) the table that should have been on the next page shows up on the first. What I want is a Javascript that does kind of the same thing I do then I click "ctr+enter" in Word (Or just anything that will solbe the problem

My page is here: http://p.altidsjov.dk/bingo/print_boards.php?collection=2

Regards Lukas.

Comment: use window.location to open a new page , and disable the url bar so that it can only print not move back or further

Comment: It may be a duplicate, but I like to read the syntax and stuff, and the link is broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the css propety `page-break-after: always`, which is part of CSS3. Note however that not all browsers support it and all browsers do their 'print' in a different way.

You can see more info at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

You would add that property to every third table.

Comment: God bless you. You saved my day! :)

Comment: [Please be careful when recommending w3schools.](http://w3fools.com)